# Active menu item won't change his class after click event when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, menu, fixed

I've got a problem with top fixed menu. When i scroll the page, active class for menu is changing depending on current section - height of fixed menu, but when i click on link in menu, active class will be added to that link, but scrolling the page won't change their class anymore until i refresh the page.

```html
<div class="menu-area">
  <div class="menu-button"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#1" class="button">1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#2" class="button">2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#3" class="button">3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#4" class="button">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
  $('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");
    $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    if (e.target.hash !== '') {
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(e.target.hash).offset().top - $(".menu-area-box").outerHeight(true)
      }, 650);
      return false;
    }
  });
});

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() + $(".menu-area-box").outerHeight(true);
  $('.menu a').each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      $('.menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

I used "hash mask" to prevent #NaN in url because of 80px fixed menu, but i don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about, but are you missing a semicolon at 8th row?